# Where to put google-services.json file into eclipse project?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement the new `GCM client` on Android.

At one point, you have to enable `Google Services` for the app. After enabling `Cloud Messaging` you have to download the file `google-services.json` and put it in the `app/` or `mobile/` directory. The problem is that in my eclipse project this directories doesn't exist.

[image]

So my question is: where do I have to put this file?

Comment: Is this new way to configure your app for `GCM` ?

Comment: Yes this is new way. I have a same problem. is your problem solved? 
please, let me know solution.

Comment: I tried this new in Android Studio, and it works fine. I think in the eclipse you can just put the json file in the `root directory` such the directory has `build`, `libs` and etc...

Comment: @bjiang How did you successfully do this in Android Studio? I'm not even able to get the file.

Comment: @MikeJamesJohnson just to this [page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start), go to step 2, click that button and follow the steps.

Comment: @bjiang Ok, where exactly should I copy the file? It says the app directory. So can I put it within my res or main folder?

Comment: @MikeJamesJohnson I put in the `app` folder. If you can open a new question, I can show you the image:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that for eclipse that file is not necessary. I've managed to make the client work without it.
Just follow the steps from [Implementing GCM Client on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) and skip the part with the `google-services.json` file.

UPDATE: For Android Studio the instructions are pretty clear. The file must be put in the app/ directory of your project: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#add-config

P.S. Any vote down should go along with the reason specified in a comment, or not? :)

Comment: no more support for eclipse i think what to do now ?

Comment: This is why we recommend quoting the relevant content from the link, in addition to the link. The contents on the links tend to change...